# ElasticSearch dont return result

Tags: search, elasticsearch

im new with elastic and can't solve this problem

i have 2 requests:

1) `curl -XGET 'host/process_test_1/1/_search?title:*New*'`

it returns me

```
    {
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 116,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "process_test_1",
        "_type": "1",
        "_id": "7118_folder_1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "obj_type": "folder",
          "obj_id": 7118,
          "title": "sadasd"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "process_test_1",
        "_type": "1",
        "_id": "6780_folder_1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "obj_type": "folder",
          "obj_id": 6780,
          "title": "New Object"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
```

why it returns me an object with title "sadasd"?

and second request

```
`curl -XGET 'host/process_test_1/1/_search' -d '{"query":{"match":{"text":{"query":"*New*","operator":"and"}}}}`'
```

it returns

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [

    ]
  }
}
```

why it return me nothins if i really have one element which match (actually i have more than 50 elements with such name and different ids)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your first query is missing the parameter name `q=`

```
curl -XGET 'host/process_test_1/1/_search?q=title:*New*'
                                          ^
                                          |
                                   this is missing
```

Second, the `match` query doesn't interpret the `*` character as a wildcard, so if you want an equivalent query using the DSL for the first query above, you need to be using the `query_string` query instead:

```
curl -XGET 'host/process_test_1/1/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*New*",
      "default_field": "text"
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: hi, thanks!
can u help with another one question?
cause multi_match query also doesnt work with "\*New\*"
what i have use?

Comment: You can also use `query_string` with [multi fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_multi_field)

Comment: is there any special cases to take "spaces" in query? cause with them elastic change his behaviour and send another result

Comment: for example i run query_string with "query":"*ac d"

and in result are objects with text "New Object"

Comment: sorry, i've found inforamtion

Comment: The default operator used if no explicit operator is specified. For example, with a default operator of OR, the query capital of Hungary is translated to capital OR of OR Hungary, and with default operator of AND, the same query is translated to capital AND of AND Hungary. The default value is OR.